# Automatic redirect to login page if not authenticated does not work with custom OnRedirectToAccessDenied delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using cookie authentication in my asp.net core web app. The default behavior is that if the user is not authenticated and tries to access some page which needs an authenticated user he gets redirected to the login page with an URL parameter `ReturnUrl` set to the page requested in the first place.
If the user is authenticated and tries to access a page which he has no authorization for he gets redirected to `/Account/AccessDenied` by default.

Because I want to implement some custom exception and status code handling into the application, I need my web app to return a `403` if the user is not authorized (but authenticated), instead of just redirecting to `/Account/AccessDenied`. I did some research and found out that you can define a custom delegate for `OnRedirectToAccessDenied` which I used to omit the redirect and just return a `403`:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

Now this works as expected and I receive a `403` for authenticated but not authorized users. But now the automatic redirect to the login page for not authenticated users stopped working (literally by just adding this custom delegate). Not authenticated users are receiving the `403` as well. So I changed the delegate to handle this case:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect($"{options.LoginPath}?ReturnUrl={context.Request.Path}");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

This as well works as expected, but feels a bit hacky. I would like to rely on the default behavior for not authenticated users, but can't find a way on how the right approach would be in this case.

How should I handle this scenario the correct way, where I want to return just a `403` for authenticated but not authorized users, but redirect not authenticated users to the login page?

---

The reason I want this behavior is because I'm registering the `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` middleware in `startup` to be able to customize the handling of different status codes:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
```

Comment: You could change the AccessDeniedPath to e.g. /Error/403 for cookie auth, would that work? Though then the URL would show in the bar :/

Comment: @juunas Thank you for your comment, but I would preferable get rid of the redirect and only return a `403`.